# Yii model findAll memory_limit

Tags: php, yii, findall

When I use `findAll()` function it `retuns` an array of `CActiveRecord` `objects`, but when I have to do an export on big data this `array` exceed allowed `memory size`.

For example:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->with = array('relation_a', 'relation_b');
$criteria->condition = "condition_a=:a AND condition_b=:b";
$data = MyModel::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Now `$data` is an array of `active record`.
Can I have something like `CDbDataReader` to get `MyModel` one by one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such thing when dealing with CActiveRecord. Even if there was such an option, php would still need to store your objects somewhere, just like how CDbDataReader works unless unbuffered queries were used (which would then place the strain on your database server).

You either need to try and reduce memory footprint with your loaded objects (select only what you need, lazy load relationships if needed) or stick with the query builder to further reduce memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can add $criteria->limit=100,And then you will not over memory size.